# Changing bloginfo description from a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, filters

How can I change the site's bloginfo description in runtime from a plugin?
I tried these, but none of them work:

```
add_filter('description', 'ab_arq_generate');
add_filter('blogdescription', 'ab_arq_generate');
```

My point would be to make a random quote in the place of the description regardless of the actual template.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're lookign for the `bloginfo` filter.

```
<?php
add_filter( 'bloginfo', 'wpse33522_change_bloginfo', 10, 2 );
function wpse33522_change_bloginfo( $text, $show )
{
    if ('description' == $show) {
        $text = 'Some New Description';
    }
    return $text;
}
```